# ntpstat from c++ program

Tags: linux

I'm working on linux.
I need to check the ntpstat from my program (c++)

1. If there is a better way than sending the command to shell with popen let me know.
2. Even sending the ntpstat comand to shell doesn't work.
   ntpstat > WritteItToFile  doesn't work also, the output is written to screen and not to file.

Comment: read the source code for ntpstat and incorporate that into your program?

Comment: Isn't it a problem for a company to use this code, in header it's written "This code is released under the terms of the FSF GPL version 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I download the code of ntpstat. It might be better to do it this way, i think i'll stay with popen as...
2. as is found the problem. The error wasn't written in the file because it was in stderr.
   the solution is to writte the following, so stderr will go to stdout.
   ntpstat 2>&1